# Rails running tests Mysql::Error: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I'm trying to run some tests and I keep getting this error :

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO ...
```

I have a Mac OX 10.9.2 and I'm using mysql2 gem. 
I get the error only for some of the entities.
Is strange for me because I'm using the same schema on an machine with ubuntu and every thing is working with no problems.

Is there a issue with mysql2 gem on mac or maybe something to be aware on mac related to this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the table you are trying to update has a primary key "id" field but no auto_increment defined on the field.  You have to add auto_increment.  You can do this either directly with msql or through a Ruby Rails migration.

(1) MYSQL  (remember to use ; or \g to end the line)

mysql>  ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN field_name INT AUTO_INCREMENT;

(2) RAILS

project_dir> rails generate migration table_name_autoincrement

Then edit the migration file that rails generates for you.  Mine was:
..\project_dir\db\migrate\20170415233610_section_edits_autoincrement.rb

```
class SectionEditsAutoincrement < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]

  def change

    execute "ALTER TABLE section_edits MODIFY COLUMN id INT AUTO_INCREMENT;"

  end

end
```

Save and then run rake migrate:

project_dir>rake db:migrate